# JaCoCo Android Coverage with Ant

Tags: java, android, ant, jacoco

I have been working on a project that I want to start using JaCoCo. I was wondering if you could help me with an issue I have been having. The project is using Ant to automate building & testing and has an Android component. I have been trying to integrate JaCoCo coverage reports into the project, but have not made much progress when it comes to Android.

Unfortunately, the documentation for the [Ant tasks](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/ant.html) are not all that detailed and the [off-line example](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/build-offline.xml) is only the most basic case. I found [examples of how to use Maven](https://github.com/Godin/jacoco-experiments/tree/android), but nothing for Ant. I found [vague](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/44) [references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin#comment30144275_18358297) to the fact that JaCoCO on Android does work, but not explanation of how it all works.

I was able to do the off-line instrumentation by putting that task in a `-post-compile` target the `custom_rule.xml` file within the Android project folder. However, I'm not sure about how to properly configure the java agent to run and retrieve the .exec file to use for generating a report.

- Should the java agent be in the `libs` directory of the main project or the test project?
- Should I be putting a `jacoco-agent.properties` in the project's `libs` folder? Or is there a better way to configure the agent?
- What is the easiest way to write the output to a file on the host computer? Is a TCP connection better than dumping to a file on the device that could then be copied off of the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, according to this issue at eclemma/jacoco you do not need the tcp connection...

[issue44 jacoco/eclemma](https://github.com/jacoco/eclemma/issues/44)

ignore jacoco-agent.properties as you are supply the same properties in the ant task anyway hence no need for that properties file as what I read of the ant task parameters

Comment: The problem is that these test have to run in the Android emulator, not in the JVM. The Android build script launches the tests with an `exec` task that calls `adb`. This cannot be done inside of a `jacoco:coverage` task. If you understand this, can you provide an example of how you mean to launch the tests and configure the properties?

Comment: I ended up scrapping the emulator and using Robolectric so that I can run it inside a standard JVM.  Robolectric is convaluted but once you get the hang of it you can then take and run your coverage .  Runs alot faster and easier to load to things like sonar.