# How to generate jacoco.exec file with Gradle Plugin in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, jacoco

I already read some articules related to [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin), [**this**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jacoco/Pjb0NP1kc-A) and [**this**](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_1_6_jacoco_in_multi_module_build) but I could not found the answer.
Using the Gradle Plugin in Android Studio, I can't generate the file jacoco.exec (neither *.exec in any subfolder).

> What do I have to set in the build.gradle file in order to generate this file?

Note: Remember that I'm using the Gradle Plugin (which is different) and Android Studio.

Comment: Any luck about this issue ?

Comment: I didn't have any luck with this :(

Answer (score 5):

By default `Gradle` `connectedInstrumentTest` task generates test reports in `.ec` format (`Emma`).
If you need `jacoco.exec` report file you need `Robolectric + JUnit` tests instead of `Android` unit tests (based on `InstrumentationTestCase`).
[Here](http://raptordigital.blogspot.com/2014/08/code-coverage-reports-using-robolectric.html) is an example of `JaCoCo` `Gradle` plugin configuration.

Comment: Just wanted to add that you should ensure you're debug project has the 'testCoverageEnabled true' setting, and jacoco coverage will be generated like magic.

Comment: If you add "testCoverageEnabled true" and use InstrumentationTestCase without Robolectric, then you will get just jacoco.ec coverage file and not jacoco.exec. It's a main point. Of course you will see jacoco reports (html, xml) in build folder. But, such systems as Sonar, doesn't support .ec reports, they need .exec file :(