# Junit4 and Jacoco wont work in Android Studio?

Tags: android, junit, gradle, junit4, jacoco

I try to get code coverage using Jacoco in Android Studio. When I write @SmallTest and enter

`$./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport`

it gives me coverage perfectly. It is created in

> build/outputs/reports/coverage/debug/index.html

and test report is in ;

> build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html

When I add plugin Junit4 in gradle.build file , change the @SmallTest annotation to @Test and enter

```
   '$./gradlew test'
```

it runs the tests and gives me the results in different directory which is ;

> build/test-report/index.html

But when I run  createDebugCoverageReport in this case (with JUnit 4) coverage is empty and test report says there is no test, first directory I mention about (build/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html). 
But in the second directory (build/test-report/index.html) I can see that my tests are exist and passed.

Before you ask after every execution I run;

```
'$./gradlew clean'
```

to be sure there is no leftover reports.

I add the directory screenshoots below .

Anyone have a suggestion. How do I run JUnit4 and Jacoco together ?

P.S : Sorry for my english it is not my native language.
Images : 
Without Junit4 plugin
http://s28.postimg.org/7dj9kdk31/Screen_Shot_2014_11_18_at_19_01_41.png

http://s9.postimg.org/4v9qsx9vj/Screen_Shot_2014_11_18_at_19_01_57.png

Comment: AFAIK Junit4 is not supported at the moment.

Comment: I found a solution. The main problem is I should define testClass to gradle. Thanks to this guy answer ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin