# Android Jacoco Test with Gradle dependsOn order with compileDebugSources and compileDebugTestSources

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco

Other places like [This Other Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin) will have a jacocoTestReport task that depends on testDebug. Which works.

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: "testDebug") {
    ...
}
```

However, in my case, I need to also depend on the android tasks compileDebugSources and compileDebugTestSources in addition to the testDebug. So I was hoping that the following would work

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ["compileDebugSources", "compileDebugTestSources", "testDebug"]) {
    ...
}
```

However, when I use the dependsOn property or method, the order of these dependencies aren't guaranteed as stated by Gradle. So I wanted to do something like the following outside of the task

```
 testDebug.mustRunAfter compileDebugSources
 testDebug.mustRunAfter compileDebugTestSources
```

but I get a compilation problem with the above is that testDebug or compileDebugSources or compileDebugTestSources gets marked as being "Could not find property 'testDebug/compileDebugSources/compileDebugTestSources'" on project :app

I'm wondering what I need to do in order to add the order of these tasks for my existing jacocoTestReport task in gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: ["compileDebugSources", "compileDebugTestSources", "testDebug"]) { ... }
tasks.testDebug.dependsOn(compileDebugTestSources)
tasks.compileDebugTestSources.dependsOn(compileDebugSources)
```