# Generating Code Coverage Report with Android Studio 1.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to generate a Code Coverage report using Android Studio and the gradle plugin.

I've done alot of research and seem to have found that using the jacoco plugin is the way to do it. I currently only have instrumentation and junit tests which I run with the gradle wrapper using gradle 1.13 that I execute with `./gradlew connectedCheck`.

The appropriate part of my gradle file looks like this:

```
    mock.initWith(debug)
    mock {
        testCoverageEnabled true
    }
```

Upon doing so it generates a coverage.ec file that I have no idea what to do with. Apparently you need a coverage.em file for emma to compile it but I'm not sure where to generate that.

I've also tried this without a gradle wrapper using gradle 2.2.1

According to http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#jacoco-application-output it should be generating an html file with the coverage report in it but I am unable to do so. Does anyone have any great tutorials or a way to use the coverage.ec file?

Comment: Checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24231246/836540