# Android: Code coverage tool using Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, test-coverage

I have written test cases for iOS and there we have

> XcodeCoverage

for finding out the code coverage. Now, I wish to do same for my android test cases. Is there any tool compatible with **Android Studio** itself?
Any suggestions/ reference links would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

using Android Studio 1.4 (and probably 1.1+), you have the ability to get the coverage while running your tests without additional plugins.

[image: overview]

If you can't see the Run 'All Tests' with coverage button, you can find out why [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JaCoCo plugin, which is fairly new, but in general does the job more than enough. You can get more details about it here : [Android test code coverage with JaCoCo Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18358297/android-test-code-coverage-with-jacoco-gradle-plugin/24231246#24231246)

Comment: MasterJohn will it integrate with Studio itself?

Comment: Of course, here's a tutorial on how to do so: [link](http://scrapbook.patrickmclaren.com/)

Comment: MasterJohn I followed above link. but couldn't find createDebugCoverageReport task.